# How to change .gltf buffer uri in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gltf

Information of the .gltf file that already exists. Information of the .gltf file that already exists.
.
.
.

```
"buffers" : [
            {
                "byteLength" : 472360,
                "uri" : "non-existent-file.bin"
            }
        ]
```

This is my code that I want to change the Buffer URI of this file after loading it first.

```
> var loader = new GLTFLoader();
> 
>   loader.load(
>     exist_gltf_file_path,
>     (gltf) => {
>       gltf.buffers[0].uri = gltf.buffers[0].uri.replace("non-existent file.bin", "new_file.bin");
>     },
>     (xhr) => {
>       console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
>     },
>     (error) => {
>       console.log("An error happened");
>     }   );
```

Here an error occurs in load because the uri path of the buffer does not exist. I'd like to change my URI before LOAD, what should I do?

Comment: It seems to be a string you can change with a text editor. It's hard to tell what your actual problem is without more code and context.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you won't be able to successfully call `GLTFLoader` `.load()` function with an invalid glTF buffer as part of the file.

The `.load` function does two things:  (1) It fetches (async) and parses the JSON from the server, and then (2) it parses the resulting object as glTF.  The problem is you're trying to edit the thing between steps (1) and (2), but this `.load` function is doing both.

I don't know about the reactjs version, but if this is based on ThreeJS, the [`GLTFLoader`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader) class has another helper function called `.parse(...)` that takes different arguments and only does step (2) mentioned above.  Note that this is NOT a `JSON.parse` (which happened in step 1), this is parsing the resulting JSON object tree into a full glTF 3D model.  So you would then need to take care of step (1) yourself, possibly [doing it the way GLTFLoader does it](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/9ef27d1af7809fa4d9943f8d4c4644e365ab6d2d/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js#L108-L161).

But this gives you the chance to make edits to the loaded/parsed JSON before asking GLTFLoader to then parse the resulting object into a 3D model.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As you said, I'd like to start by bringing GLTF files to JSON, but no matter how much I look for them, they won't work because of buffer uri error.  could you please tell me what the problem is?@emackey

Comment: @jonywoong the error means the buffer file (`.bin`) at that URL does not exist. If you don't have all parts of the file, you can't load it. I would recommend getting the complet model (which may include multiple files!) and testing on a viewer like https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ first.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace with regex

```js
const data = {
  buffers: [
    {
      byteLength: 472360,
      uri: "494E996610D342DF.bin",
    },
  ],
}

data.buffers[0].uri = data.buffers[0].uri.replace(/.*(.bin)/, "yournewname$1")

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to replace the URI of the existing gltf file, but what should I do? I am attaching the code below to help you understand.

Comment: var loader = new GLTFLoader();
  loader.load(
    res.editorAsset.threeD,
    (gltf) => {
           gltf.buffers[0].uri.replace(/.*(.bin)/, "newUri.bin File");
    },
    (xhr) => {
      console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log("An error happened");
    }
  );

Comment: @jonywoong you must reassign that `gltf.buffers[0].uri = gltf.buffers[0].uri.replace(/.*(.bin)/, "newUri$1")`

Comment: sry sir... when i load gltf file, error is occur.. that error caused by buffer uri because 494E996610D342DF.bin file doesn't exist .. I think we should change URI before we do load, but... What should I do?